# HTML source code being printed as raw data from database

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

I save html in my database and when I recover this html in my view I see it like text in my browser and not html tags.

Example :

I save `"<div><h1>Hello</h1></div>"`

But when I echo it, the browser prints the tags as raw data, and not as HTML markup.

Comment: Not clear about how to go about this... But won't a WYSWYG editor like tinyMCE help in this case?

Comment: It doesn't help in this case, I want to see HTML save in my database not as text but in what it would be created for: exemple If i save <h1>hello</h1> i doesn't whant to see <h1>hello</h1> but the title "hello"

Comment: How is this data being saved?

Comment: By an ajax post, I set a var who contain the html ($(this).html()) and after that I send it to my PHP who sent it to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what I want ! Juste use htmlspecialchars_decode() and it works !

Answer (score 0):

I guess you echo it like `{{$string}}`
This works same as `e() function (PHP: htmlentities)` 
in order to echo html in Laravel Blade echo it like this `{!! $string !!}` to pass over HTML clean

Answer (score 0):

By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

Hello, `{!! $name !!}`

Comment: It doesn't work I didn't see the title I already see the html in text

Comment: can you write your code in the question, and which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @if($new->type == 'header')
     {!! $new->contenu !!}
@endif

I use the last version of Laravel

Comment: Than you are doing it ryt, coz in laravel 5 and 5.1 this is the way of doing it, whereas in laravel 4.2 it was this
 {{{ $name }}}

Comment: Yes it was I have read but I doeasn't understand why code was see in text and not what I want ....